# Angular: drag and drop items are not in the same order as before when loading from database

Tags: angular, database, drag-and-drop

I use the drag and drop component from Angular.

https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting

With each drop, the items are saved in a postgres database.
When I load the items from the database, the items are in a different order.

**How can I ensure that the data is loaded from the database in the same order as it was shown in the frontend?**

Here's what I thought, but I'm looking for a simpler solution:

I could add an extra column in the database to store the order of the items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you may to add extra column often call `displayOrder`. For the sorting, a `OrderBy` in your SQL request is ok or you can do that in front with the `sort` javascript function.

If you do that ALL users can modify the order of each item. If each item is unique per user it's ok. Otherwise if User Alice see the Item 1 and User Bob see the Item 1 too and Alice modify the `displayOrder` of Item 1, Bob'll be impacted too. A join table will be needed with `UserId` `ItemId` `displayOrder`.

I hope I helped you :)

Comment: But changing one item's position requires tons of records to be updated. Reordering items at database-level is not easy. I've tried with stern-brocot trees but this also quite rapidly results in limitations... Do you have ideas for that?